# How to convert time to string in php

Tags: php, postgresql, psql

I have a php foreach loop which fetch data from a different database and Insert it into my other database table. My problem is when I ran this code I got an error in my time column. Maybe because I have to convert the time to a string as my table excepts text in time column.

My error code:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "22"
SELECT 897196,2018-02-26 22:20:09,1...
                         ^ - error
```

So, I put string in from of the time variable, but still the same error. Though I am not sure about the problem to be quite honest.

My Php code

```
foreach($results as $n){

$id = $n['ID'];
$time = (string)$n['Time']=='0000-00-00 00:00:00'?null:(string)$n['Time'];
$email= $n['email'];
$marks= $n['marks'];
$rank= $n['rank'];


$psql->get_db()->beginTransaction();


    $stmt = $psql->pdo_prepared("INSERT INTO student(
        id, time,email, marks, rank) SELECT $id,$time, $email,$marks,$rank FROM student WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM student WHERE id = $id AND time = $time AND email= $email AND marks = $marks AND rank= $rank)");

$psql->get_db()->commit();
}
```

Thank you in Advance;

Comment: put the quote mark 'time'

Comment: now it give the error on quote mark :Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'time'"

Comment: please use double quote, since you used single quote before

Comment: but i have double quotes around my insert statement?

Comment: do you mean something like this  $stmt = $psql->pdo_prepared("INSERT INTO student(
        id, "time",email, marks, rank) SELECT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change this line

```
$time = (string)$n['Time']=='0000-00-00 00:00:00'?null:(string)$n['Time'];
```

to this

```
$time = (string)$n['Time']=='0000-00-00 00:00:00'  ? null : '"'.(string)$n['Time'] .'"';
```

Comment: In your code the time value will set like this `2018-02-26 22:20:09` the free space in this value create that error. In mysql operation the string values must be wrapped with `'` or `"` quotes. in my code the time value will set like this :`"2018-02-26 22:20:09"`

Comment: Oh ok, but I have an another issue, if I was having an html elements inside a php variable, how can we convert them into string. With your method it seams difficult as HTML elements will have id="xyz" or style:''. How to do that?